# Sorting pos/neg numbers with fractional parts using Unix sort

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

Using `sort (coreutils) 5.2.1`

I have the following file, which I'd like to sort by the non-integer part of field 4. This can be a negative or positive number, and might also have the value INF.

```
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=0.123 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=4.22 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=5.77 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.92 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.91 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
```

I would like this to be sorted as

```
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.92 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.91 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=0.123 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=4.22 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=5.77 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
```

Given that the number part of the field is at character position 4 (assuming the indexing starts at 0, and I'm not sure of this), I have tried `sort` with the following options:

- `sort -g -k4.4 inputfile`
- `sort -g -k4.5 inputfile`
- `sort -n -k4.4 inputfile`
- `sort -n -k4.5 inputfile`
- `sort -g inputfile`

These all yield the following, which is close, but not quite right. The magnitudes are sorted correctly, but I'd like the most negative value on top.

```
field1 field2 field3 tag=0.123 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.91 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.92 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=4.22 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=5.77 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
```

How can I make `sort` behave?

FWIW, here's more information:

```
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 6)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result. It sorts as expected with the `tag=` removed, and in the first field, but not in any other fields with `tag=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on a Mac, so it may be a slightly different implementation, but I found this to work:

`sort -gb -k 4.5,4 inputfile`

In English: "**sort**, in a **-g**eneral numeric fashion, ignoring **-b**lanks, the file **inputfile** using the **4**th **-k(c)**olumn's data, from the **5**th element in that column to the end of the data in the **4**th column"

```
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.92 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.91 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=0.123 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=4.22 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=5.77 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
```

Comment: Indeed `sort -gb -k4.5 inputfile` works... removing the `-b` option reverts it to the faulty sort I showed above. Looking at `man sort`, `-b` is listed as "ignore leading blanks". I'm not sure why that helps us here, but I do like the results.

Comment: Also, could you explain what the purpose of `-k4.5,4` is? As I understand the key option, that means to start at the fifth character of field four and stop at the beginning of field four.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a pre-processing awk step that adds a new field at the end containing the numeric portion or the numeric representation from field 4, and sort by this field. Add a post-processing step to strip this field. Note that in the example below, `INF` has been set to an arbitrary high value of `10**10`, you can set it to a higher value if you have a naturally occurring number in the input that exceeds this value

```
awk '{x=$4; sub("tag=", "", x); sub("INF", 10**10, x); print $0, x}' file.txt |
sort -k7,7g | 
cut -f-6 -d' '
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.92 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=-1.91 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=0.123 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=4.22 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=5.77 field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
field1 field2 field3 tag=INF field5 field6
```